# iOS updated app crashing on opening due to GULHeartbeatDateStorage.m file

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, crash

I have updated my app and on first open it's crashing. I am using FirebaseDatabase, Firebase, FirebaseMessaging, FirebaseCore in my app.
FirebaseApp.configure() is added in AppDidFinishLaunching
Firebase version on previous build was 7.10.0 current build which is crashing is having firebase version 7.11.0.
Is the problem happening due to pod update or is this some other issue?

Crashlytics Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run `pod update`.

This looks like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8047 which is solved by updating to version 7.4.1 of the GoogleUtilities pod.

Comment: Great! Welcome to stackoverflow and please mark the answer accepted.